# How to use input from selectInput to slice data

Tags: r, shiny

I have similar issue to [R Shiny selectInput](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34929206/r-shiny-selectinput-that-is-dependent-on-another-selectinput/58083104#58083104), I would like to use the `input` to slice my data like this:

```
selectInput("category", "Choose a Category:",
                            choices = c('Any', levels(as.factor(unique(BD$DX_01_Cat))))), 

uiOutput("secondSelection")
```

```
if (input$category != "Any"){
       subsetSubsTab <<- subsetSubsTab[subsetSubsTab$DX_01_Cat==input$category];

output$secondSelection <- renderUI({
       selectInput("subdiagnosis", "Choose a Subdiagnosis:", choices = c("Any", as.character(subsetSubsTab[subsetSubsTab$DX_01_Cat==input$category, DX_01_Sub])) , selected = "Any")
     })

if (input$subdiagnosis != "Any"){
       subsetSubsTab <<- subsetSubsTab[subsetSubsTab$DX_01_Sub==input$subdiagnosis];
     }
```

but the last `if statement` does not work.

I get warning `Warning: Error in if: argument is of length zero`, 
the `subsetSubsTab` actualize for a second and goes back. Could someone help please?

Comment: A simplification, replace `choices = c('Any', levels(as.factor(unique(BD$DX_01_Cat)))))` with `choices = c('Any', (unique(BD$DX_01_Cat))`

Comment: Can't really tell without a more complete example, but it seems like once your data is filtered, there's no one to go back to the original. You overwrite `subsetSubs` which each subset, so it can only get smaller...

Comment: Since your error is with the `if` statement using `input$subdiagnosis` (you say), it would be nice if you showed that `selectInput` instead of just the `category` selector, which you say is working...