# R Shiny Dependent Dropdown Fields - values are not saved

Tags: r, shiny, dropdown

I am building a data entry form for property management and using shiny.

Problem:
I have a dorpdown field (outputId = `robapp`) which is dependent on the selection of another dropdownfield (inputId = `rob`).

I managed that the displayed values in `robapp` are dependent on the selection in `rob`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34929206/r-shiny-selectinput-that-is-dependent-on-another-selectinput).

However, the selected value from `robapp` is not saved when I click on the `Übermitteln`-Button (which binds my new entered data with my dataframe `tdata`.
I tried so many different solutions but I can't write the selected value in `robapp` in my `save_data` variable.

Any help is appreciated. Many thanks.

**Preparing data**

```
# tdata holds information of the tenants, new information entered via the form are added
tdata <- data.frame(matrix(rep(LETTERS,17), nrow = 1, ncol = 17))
colnames(tdata) <- c("Anrede", "Titel", "Vorname",
                     "Nachname", "Geburtsdatum", "Geburtsort", 
                     "Familienstand", "Telefonnummer", "E-Mail", 
                     "Beruf", "Arbeitgeber", "Abschluss Arbeitsvertrag", 
                     "Datum Mietbeginn", "Mietobjekt", "Appartment", 
                     "Miete (mtl.)", "Nebenkosten (mtl.)" )


# create list that holds the data of the rentable objects
rent_obj <- list(       c("Astreet",       "1",    1234, "MickeymouseHill"),
                        c("Bstreet", "74",    5678, "GothamCity"), 
                        c("CStreet",    "8",    9101, "Wonderland"),
                        c("DStreet",  "10",  1213, "Valhalla"), 
                        c("EStreet",  "10",    1415, "Heaven")
                        
                )

# create empty list to hold labels consisting of "Streetname Housenumber, Zip Place"
obj_label <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(rent_obj))

# create names to show in dropdown list
local(
  for (i in 1:length(rent_obj))
  {
   obj           <- rent_obj[[i]]                                                     # unlist adress data of object i
   strt_obj      <- paste(obj[1], obj[2], sep = " ")                                  # paste rent. object's street and housenumber
   zip_obj       <- paste( paste(strt_obj, obj[3], sep = ", "), obj[4], sep = " " )   # paste street, housenumber and zip code and place together
   obj_label[i] <<- zip_obj                                                           # overwrite vector rent_obj with created labels
  }
)

############################
# Adding Appartment Numbers
############################

# creating empty list for appartments per rentable object
app_no        <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(rent_obj)) # length is total number of rent. objects

# name list entries with addresses of rent. objects
names(app_no) <- obj_label

# assigning appartment labels to rent. objects

app_no[[1]] <- c("EG rechts", "EG links", "1. OG rechts", "1. OG links", "Dach rechts", "Dach links")
app_no[[2]] <- as.character(1:14)
app_no[[3]] <- c("EG rechts", "EG links", "1. OG rechts", "1. OG links", "Dach rechts")
app_no[[4]] <- c("App 1", "App 2")
app_no[[5]] <- as.character(1:6)
```

**UI**

```
##################################
# Creating UserInterface For Form
##################################

# create user interface of form
ui <- dashboardPage(
                    dashboardHeader(title = "Stammdaten-Eingabe"),    # set title for form
                    dashboardSidebar(),
                    dashboardBody( 
                      
                                  ###########
                                  # Fields & Labels
                                  ###########
                                  
                                  fluidRow(     
                                  #--- Anrede ---#
                                  column(width = 2, selectInput( inputId = "sal",      label = "Anrede", choices = list("Herr", "Frau"),       selected = "NULL" )),
                                  
                                  #--- Titel ---#
                                  column(width = 2, selectInput( inputId = "deg",      label = "Titel",  choices = list("\n", "Dr.", "Prof."), selected = "\n"   )),    # "\n" creates blank entry
                                  
                                  #--- Vorname ---#
                                  column(width = 2, textInput(   inputId = "fn",       label = "Vorname",  value = ""             )),
                                  
                                  #--- Nachname ---#
                                  column(width = 2, textInput(   inputId = "ln",       label = "Nachname", value = ""             )),
                                  
                                  #--- Geburtsdatum ---#
                                  column(width = 2, dateInput(   inputId = "dob",      label = "Geburtsdatum"                     )),
                                  
                                  #--- Geburtsort ---#
                                  column(width = 2, textInput(   inputId = "pob",      label = "Geburtsort", value = ""           )),
                                  ), # close fluidRow
                                  
                                  fluidRow(
                                  #--- Familienstand ---#
                                  column(width = 2, selectInput( inputId = "ms",       label = "Familenstand", choices = list("Ledig", "Verheiratet"), selected = "\n"  )),
                                  
                                  #--- Telefonnummer ---#
                                  column(width = 2, textInput(   inputId = "pn",       label = "Telefonnummer", value = ""         )),
                                  
                                  #--- E-Mail ---#
                                  column(width = 2, textInput(   inputId = "em",       label = "E-Mail", value = ""                )),
                                  
                                  #--- Beruf ---#
                                  column(width = 2, textInput(   inputId = "job",      label = "Beruf", value = ""                 )),
                                  
                                  #--- Arbeitgeber ---#
                                  column(width = 2, textInput(   inputId = "emp",      label = "Arbeitgeber", value = ""           )),
                                  
                                  #--- Abschluss Arbeitsvertrag ---#
                                  column(width = 2, dateInput(   inputId = "dec",      label = "Datum Arbeitsvertrag"              )),
                                  ), # close fluidRow
                                  
                                  fluidRow(
                                  #--- Datum Mietbeginn ---#
                                  column(width = 2, dateInput(   inputId = "drs",      label = "Mietbeginn"                        )),
                                 
                                  
                                  #--- Mietobjekt ---#
                                  column(width = 2, selectInput( inputId = "rob",      label = "Mietobjekt", choices = obj_label, selected = "\n"  )),
                                  
                                   
                                  #--- Mietobjekt - Appartment-Nummer ---#
                                  column(width = 2, uiOutput(   outputId = "robapp",   label = "Appartment", value = ""             )), 
                                  
                                  
                                  #--- Miete ---#
                                  # CurrencyPlacement = "s" currency appears right to entered value
                                  # decimalCharacter separates decimal places
                                  # digitGroupSeparator indicates thousands seperator
                                 
                                  column(width = 2, autonumericInput(inputId = "rinst", label = "Miete (mtl.)", value = "", min = 0, currencySymbol = "€", currencySymbolPlacement = "s", decimalPlaces = 2, decimalCharacter = ",", digitGroupSeparator = "."  )),
                                  
                                  #--- Nebenkosten ---#
                                  # CurrencyPlacement = "s" currency appears right to entered value
                                  # decimalCharacter separates decimal places
                                  # digitGroupSeparator indicates thousands seperator
                                  
                                  column(width = 2, autonumericInput(inputId = "addc",  label = "Nebenkosten (mtl.)", value = "", min = 0, currencySymbol = "€", currencySymbolPlacement = "s", decimalPlaces = 2, decimalCharacter = ",", digitGroupSeparator = "."  )),
                                  ), # close fluidRow
                                  
                                  #############
                                  # BUTTONS
                                  #############
                                  actionButton("addbutton", "Übernehmen")
                                  
                                  
                              )# close dashboardBody
                    )# close dashboardPage
```

**Server**

```
# create server function 
server <- function(input, output, session)
{
  
  ############
  # Dependent Dropdown (Rent. Obj. -> Appartment No.)
  ###########
  
  
    
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34929206/r-shiny-selectinput-that-is-dependent-on-another-selectinput
output$robapp <- renderUI({ selectInput(
                                         inputId = "rob", 
                                         label   = "Appartment", 
                                         choices = list( app_no[which(names(app_no)==input$rob)])[[1]] #input$rob is field name of rentable object's address, [[1]] unlists list which contains appartment numbers of filtered address
                                         ) # close selectInput
                            }) # close renderUI 
 


 # your action button condition
observe({ if(input$addbutton > 0) 
   {# start if
   # create the new line to be added from your inputs
   newLine <- isolate(c(input$sal,   input$deg, input$fn, 
                        input$ln,    input$dob, input$pob, 
                        input$ms,    input$pn,  input$em, 
                        input$job,   input$emp, input$dec,
                        input$drs,   input$rob, input$robapp,
                        input$rinst, input$addc))
   # update your data
   # note the unlist of newLine, this prevents a bothersome warning message that the rbind will return regarding rownames because of using isolate.
   isolate(updated_values <- rbind(as.matrix(tdata), unlist(newLine)))
   save_data <<- updated_values
   } # close if
  })# close observe

 
 
 
 } # close server function
```

**Launch App**

```
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

I referenced an incorrect field in the renderUI function.

Correct solution (using the second dropdown's inputId):

```
output$robapp <- renderUI({ selectInput(
                                         inputId = "robapp", 
                                         label   = "Appartment", 
                                         choices = list( app_no[which(names(app_no)==input$rob)])[[1]] #input$rob is field name of rentable object's address, [[1]] unlists list which contains appartment numbers of filtered address
                                         ) # close selectInput
                            }) # close renderUI
```